# How can i upload images from mobile devices using a standard website? (no phonegap)

Tags: php, codeigniter, mobile

I'm working into an application that is used by multiple browsers and plataforms. The only problem I'm facing at this moment is how can i upload pictures from mobile devices since i'm not using phonegap. Any help?

If it helps, I'm using codeigniter as a backend framework.

Comment: Using a simple file upload form …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<input type="file">` works fine on iOS 6+ and Android 2.2+, which covers the vast majority of traffic you'll see. A full list is available here: http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/file-upload-support-on-mobile/

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Very useful

Answer (score -1):

You can upload your images to the webserver / codelgniter app with any application that supports http requests. This could be a native mobile app, a mobile website in your browser etc. The hardest part is the user authentication and authorization with your backend (webserver). For this you will have to think about Token-based authentication or similar techniques.